# Bootstrap columns enlarge the more I type in a search bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

When typing in to an `input` search bar, my Bootstrap `div .col-xs-4` enlarges, breaking out of it's container. What's odd is, Developer Tools doesn't seem to show any changes in the code that would affect this.

To replicate this problem, try typing the full name of one of the images in this JSFiddle gallery i.e., "Satcom 2016", and watch the `div` burst out of it's container. Clearing the input then shows that every `div` has expanded, not just the visible ones.

**JSFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/vadrfgvv/

**jQuery**

```
function rowBreak(input) {
  $('.col-flex').hide();
  if (input) {
    $('.row-flex').replaceWith(function() {
      return $(this).html();
    });
    $('.col-flex').wrapAll('<div class="row">');
  }
  $('.col-visible').each(function(i, e) {
    if (((i + 1) % 3 == 0) && ($(this).siblings().length != 2)) {
      var x = $('.col-visible:gt(' + i + ')');
      $('<div class="row">').append(x).insertAfter(this.closest('div.row'));
    }
  });
  $('.col-visible').show();
}

rowBreak(0);

$('#search').on('keyup', function() {
  $('.col-flex').removeClass('col-visible').hide();
  var s = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $('.col-flex').filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('h4').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(s) > -1;
  }).show().addClass('col-visible');
  rowBreak(s);
});

$('#results').on('click', '.panel-search', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('panel-default').toggleClass('panel-success');
  $(this).find('.panel-body').toggleClass('bg-green');

  var image = $(this).find('img');
  var imageID = image.attr('id');
  // alert(image.width());

  if ($(this).hasClass('panel-success')) {
    image.clone().appendTo('.panel-include').removeClass('img-thumbnail').css('margin-bottom', '20px').attr('id', 'x' + imageID).wrap('<p></p>');
  } else {
    $('.panel-include').find(('#x' + imageID)).closest('p').remove();
  }

  if ($('.panel-include > p').length == 0) {
    $('.panel-include').find('em').show();
  } else {
    $('.panel-include').find('em').hide();
  }
});

$('.btn-save').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var logos = '';
  $('.panel-include').find('p').each(function() {
    imageID = $(this).find('img').attr('id');
    logos += imageID;
  });
  if (logos) {
    logos = logos.substr(1);
  }
  $("input[name=ids]").val(logos);
  $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
      <input class="form-control" id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            Your Chosen Content
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body panel-include">
          <em class="text-muted">Click on some images to add them here.</em>
        </div>
      </div>
      <form action="#" method="get">
        <input type="hidden" name="ids" value="">
        <p class="text-right">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-save" type="submit">
            <i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save
          </button>
        </p>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
      <div id="results">
        <div class="row row-flex">
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-flex col-visible">
            <div class="panel panel-search panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  AEClim
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail img-gallery" src="http://placehold.it/160x100/cccccc/9a9a9a/&text=AEClim" id="1">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-flex col-visible">
            <div class="panel panel-search panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  AEMET
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail img-gallery" src="http://placehold.it/160x100/cccccc/9a9a9a/&text=AEMET" id="2">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-flex col-visible">
            <div class="panel panel-search panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  AME
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail img-gallery" src="http://placehold.it/160x100/cccccc/9a9a9a/&text=AME" id="3">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-flex col-visible">
            <div class="panel panel-search panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  APMG
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail img-gallery" src="http://placehold.it/160x100/cccccc/9a9a9a/&text=APMG" id="4">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-flex col-visible">
            <div class="panel panel-search panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  ATC Network
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail img-gallery" src="http://placehold.it/160x100/cccccc/9a9a9a/&text=ATC+Network" id="5">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-flex col-visible">
            <div class="panel panel-search panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  Meteomet
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail img-gallery" src="http://placehold.it/160x100/cccccc/9a9a9a/&text=Meteomet" id="6">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-flex col-visible">
            <div class="panel panel-search panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  MMC 2016
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail img-gallery" src="http://placehold.it/160x100/cccccc/9a9a9a/&text=MMC+2016" id="7">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-flex col-visible">
            <div class="panel panel-search panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  Satcom 2016
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail img-gallery" src="http://placehold.it/160x100/cccccc/9a9a9a/&text=Satcom+2016" id="8">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I initially thought it was the `.img-responsive` class that was causing problems (maybe the image was enlarging when the `div` was hidden?), but it seems like the image doesn't actually enlarge with the `div`, so that rules that out.

I'm not sure where else to start debugging.

*Note: I have kept the entirety of the Javascript that affects these page elements in my question/Fiddle, in case it is something there that is causing the problem.*

Comment: You are wrapping the content into a `.row` on every keyup event? That doesn't seem like a good idea..

Comment: If there is input, I first remove the `.row` (using `.replaceWith()`) and then re-add it around the correct content, I thought?

Comment: Well the JS is clearly causing the problem. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.row {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

This CSS is the cause of your problem. i didn't see exactly how, but your js code nesting a row for every character typed. and with this css in `bootstrap.css` each nested row grows larger and larger. the images expand too.

what you can do is, overwrite this css in your html file with `<style>` tag. something like:

```
<style>
    .row{
        margin-right:0px;
        margin-left:0px;
     }
</style>
```

but you should know this is only a quick fix. a hack. if i was in your place, i'd look for the reason why your code is nesting a row for every character.

Comment: You're absolutely right. The `.row`s were nesting because when I used `.wrapAll()`, I wasn't wrapping everything in `.row .row-flex`, so come the next `'keyup` it wasn't finding the correct content. https://jsfiddle.net/mpdc/vadrfgvv/1/ Thanks for the sanity check, I totally missed the nesting rows!

Comment: Glad i was able to help.